# "Accordo" versus "intesa"

Tags: word-choice, difference

Are *accordo* and *intesa* perfect synonyms, or are there cases where one is used instead of the other one? For example, in the following sentences, could I replace *accordo* with *intesa*?

> Abbiamo firmato un accordo per mantenere la proprietà degli immobili in Via Marconi.

> C'è un accordo tra di noi: non faccio concorrenza a te se tu non fai concorrenza a me.

> Siamo d'accordo: domani firmiamo il contratto di locazione.

Comment: Why don't you explain why, in your opinion, they would not perfectly interchangeable in order to have a better focused answer?

Comment: I didn't say they are not perfectly interchangeable; I am asking if they are perfectly interchangeable, or not.

Comment: kiamla, and what is the difference, if I may ask, please?

Comment: The difference is that I didn't take any position about the topic. I am simply asking what is true.

Comment: kiamla, sorry, I don't understand why you asked a question without having any opinion about the topic. As far as I can tell 'any opinion ...' is equal to 'any doubt ...', so, if this is the logic, I don't understand how you can ask a question if you don't have any doubt, that's all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't ask a question because I have an opinion; I ask a question because I don't know something. Do you ask "What time is it?" because you have an opinion about what time is? An opinion is needed for debates, not when asking a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Accordo* and *intesa* do overlap in meaning when used as “agreement”, though *accordo* is used more regarding to opinions and intentions and *intesa* with ideas and sentiments [from Sabatini Coletti dictionary]. They also have other meanings which do not overlap — for example, *accordo* can mean “chord” and *intesa* can mean “harmony” (between persons).

In the first two of your examples, *accordo* is used as synonim of “contract” and “pact” respectively, and as such can not be substituted with *intesa*.

In the last example, one could use *intesa*, though the form would need to be changed slightly (“abbiamo un’intesa”).

Comment: Accordo can also mean harmony. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/accordo_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/

Answer (score 1):

They are synonyms, indeed, and sometimes *accordo* could be replaced with *intesa*. The meaning could shift, however:

- *Abbiamo firmato l'accordo* means usually the final agreement, while *Abbiamo firmato l'intesa* can mean also the protocol of intentions.
- *C'è un accordo tra di noi* - we always do something in this way, *C'è un intesa tra noi* - we are on the same page or we have good relations (including working relations).
- *Siamo d'accordo* - we have agreed upon it, *Siamo d'intesa* - we have agreed how we do it.

There are some more examples [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intesa/).

Comment: I've never heard "siamo d'intesa". Moreover, I don't agree with the second: "c'è un'intesa tra noi" means more that we share some feeling and opinion about the context we are in, not that we're going to do something. So you'd say "c'è una bella intesa tra noi" to mean that you like that person, you feel he/she's like you.

Comment: @martina Neither have I! It sounds really weird. Nonetheless, the dictionary says that it's possible to "_essere d'intesa sul da farsi, sul come provvedere_". I also agree with you about "c'è un'intesa fra noi" meaning more like "we are on the same page; we are good about our relations (including working relations)".